# Any way to have delayed_job execute some run-once code at startup and use across all jobs?

Tags: queue, jobs, delayed-job

So I've got a delayed_job task that pushes some info to an XMPP server. Ideally you create a connection to XMPP once and then constantly push data to it, rather than creating a new connection every time you have some data to send.

Is there any kind of facility in delayed_job for running a sort of 'setup' method when a worker starts, have it set some instance variables (like the XMPP connection object) that can then be used by all the jobs that come up? It's okay if each worker runs its own setup method. I just don't want every job (thousands per day) connecting to the XMPP server from scratch every time.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I ended up just writing my own little job runner to get this done.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and accept that, if you think other SO readers might find your solution useful.

Answer (score 1):

Delayed Job now has "Hooks" (enqueue, before, after, success, error, failure) - it looks like these were added around June 2010.  The before hook would probably work in a case where you wanted to find an existing connection to reuse.